# SQL Server check constraints to check signs in positions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a column called `duration` of type `varchar(5)` in my table.

How to add a check constraint to check whether the first two characters and last two characters are numeric, and 3rd character is ":"

Ex:

```
23:25
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
create table test (
id int identity(1,1),
name varchar(5) constraint tmp_chk check(name like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]')
)
```

Test cases:

```
insert into test (name) values ('12:34')
insert into test (name) values ('12:a4')
insert into test (name) values ('12x34')
insert into test (name) values ('a2:34')
insert into test (name) values ('123:34')
```

Comment: What about if single digit numbers are not zero padded?

Comment: @Tony: then it fails the constraint. It also fails the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

if you must use varchar(5), then the answer from **[C 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11925873/65223)** is correct.  **However, if you really want to solve your problem you need to forget varchar(5) and use the [time datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)**.  Using the `Time` opens the posibility of more accuracy and even calculations, which are impossible using varchar(5).

If your `duration` can be larger than 23:59:59.9999999 (max value for a Time datatype), then you should use the flavor of `INT` to contain the max number of minutes or seconds you need and store just the total minutes or seconds.  If you duration is 5 hours and 7 minutes: `05:07` store the plain int: 307 minutes, or 18420 seconds.

Comment: Actually my duration does not exceed 60 minutes. so that Always I deal with minutes and seconds.
So please explain me how to use minutes and seconds(only) in sql server using your method and how to pass values from text box(including data types) or any other controller to the db...